# Need help Writing MySQL Queries (Alexamara Marina database)

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to self-teach myself database management using Murach books, and I found these exercises online but I don't know where to start with the last two. I am using the Alexamara Marina database to complete the following exercises.

1. Create a query that displays the following for all boats: (1 row)

- Total number of boats (name it: number_of_boats),
- the maximum rental fee (name it: highest_rental_fee),
- the shortest boat (name it:  shortest boat)

2. Modify exercise 3 (the one above) to display the same information by marina rather than as a total of all boats. (2 rows)

I appreciate any help or tips!

EDIT: I am not sure how to attach the Alexamara database file so I am pasting it on pastebin so that everyone can run and create it.(see below)

```
<a href="https://pastebin.com/zz3dMAyr">Alexamara</a>
```

Yeah I was having trouble with the site letting me paste the link on its own... Sorry

Comment: Please give more information about the database structure

Comment: @AkshatGoel I just added the link to a pastebin where I pasted the code to create Alexamara datebase. Ignore the <a> tag, it wouldn't let me paste the link on its own...

Answer (score 0):

i don't know the structure of the database you're working with, you could get it by using

```sql
SHOW COLUMNS FROM boats
```

i am assuming that the database name is 'boats' and it contains the columns 'fee' and 'length'

```sql
SELECT
  COUNT(*) AS nuber_of_boats,
  MAX(fee) AS highest_rental_fee,
  MIN(length) AS shortest_boat
FROM boats;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that a boat corresponds to the `marina_slip` table

1. Total number of boats (name it: number_of_boats)

```sql
SELECT 
COUNT(*) AS number_of_boats,
MAX(RentalFee) AS highest_rental_fee,
MIN(Length) AS shorted_boat
from MarinaSlip
```

2. Modify exercise 3 (the one above) to display the same information by marina rather than as a total of all boats. (2 rows)

```
SELECT 
COUNT(*) AS number_of_boats,
MAX(RentalFee) AS highest_rental_fee,
MIN(Length) AS shorted_boat,
MarinaNum
from MarinaSlip 
group by MarinaNum
```